# array size limit in ksh

Tags: ksh

I have the following ksh script to run:

```
temp=`<some_command>`
eval set -A array $temp
```

The variable `temp` contains the output from the command, with output as space separated strings.

But on some occasions, I would come across the following error:

```
 array: 0403-046 The specified subscript cannot be greater than 4095.
```

In this case, is there a way to set the array to the first 4096 space-separated strings in `temp`?

Another alternative is to limit the output from `<some_command>` (output to stdout) to no more than 4096 lines (one string each line). Could this be done with ksh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course use a newer version of ksh93 - with a larger limit on array sizes.  If that is not an option, try the following:

```sh
# some_command <n> produces <n> lines of text:
$ function some_command {
     echo a{1..$1} | tr ' ' $'\n'
}
$ some_command 5
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
```

This is your answer:

```sh
$ set -A array $(
     some_command 4100 | head -4096
)
$ echo ${#array[@]}
4096
```